# Android: Custom region map

Tags: android, heatmap

I am trying to implement a map(not Google maps) like in the below image, which will have a hypothetical regions(not administrative) with different colors to indicate the population density. The regions will also be clickable and cliking on that will open a small info overlay.

For now I have the sliced images for each region with multiple colors (which color to be used is determined from an API request). But I am not exactly sure how can I implement this in Android? I've been doing some research for past couple of days but couldn't find anything satisfactory so far.

Things that I am having trouble to implement:

1. Put together all those images and form the map
2. How can I detect "tap/click" event in the regions
3. In one brief conversation with a guy, he mentioned something of "greyscale overlay-map, that is not visible to the user and which determines the right area by testing against the greyscale color index", frankly I didn't understand what he meant.

Here's what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Any help or pointer to the right direction would be of great help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out www.trimaps.com, I think this is what you want. Sadly it isn't free.